# How to properly override a method mixedin by a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include, overriding

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have the following situation:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule1
  include MyModule2
  include ...

  # Note: This method statement should override the method mixedin by MyModule1.
  def my_method(*args)
    # ...
  end
end

module MyModule1
  def my_method(*args)
    raise "NotImplementedError - The :my_method is not implemented yet"
  end
end

# /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
if @my_class.my_method
  All right!
end
```

When I start my Web application browsing a page then I get the error `"NotImplementedError - The :my_method is not implemented yet"`, even if I overrode the `my_method` in `MyClass` that is including `MyModule` (as you can read in the above code). Does it happens because it loads the view before of the class? or what? How should I handle the situation in order to make `MyClass` to properly override the `my_method`?

Comment: Is `@my_class` holding a constant which is of type `Class` or is it an instance of the class?

Comment: @Iain - `@my_class` is an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: Ok, was just checking :)

Comment: If you want to check the order things are being loaded, add `def self.included(base); warn "Including #{self.to_s} into #{base.to_s}"; end` in the module, and `- warn "Entering #{__FILE__}"` (if you're using Haml?) into the view. But I see no problem with your code as it is, must be some AR magic?

Answer (score 2):

There must be more going on than what you show here, because the code you show here would certainly not invoke `#my_method` from `MyModule1`. Check very carefully that the `def my_method` in `MyClass` is not misspelled, and that it is actually occurring in a `class MyClass` block, and not within a nested `class << self` block or something like that.

If that doesn't reveal anything, go to the place in your code where the exception is coming from, and add a couple debugging print statements:

```
<% p @my_class.class %>
<% p @my_class.class.ancestors %>
```

See what that prints in the console.

Comment: It is almost what I wrote in the question. Maybe the problem is related to the other included modules.

Comment: What did the debug print statements I suggested show in the Rails console?